# Efficient way of setting up a rule

Tags: replacement

I tried to define a simple rule defining how λ acts on `ψ[n]`:

```
myrule1 = λ ψ[n_] -> α[n + 1]  ψ[n + 1];
```

The result I get is correct provided there's just one λ on the RHS of `ψ[n]`. For instance:

```
λ^2  ψ[n] //. myrule1
```

isn't computed at all. On the other hand, if I do it step by step:

```
λ α[1 + n] ψ[1 + n] /. myrule1
```

I get the correct result.  I tried to define a new rule:

```
myrule2 = λ^m_ ψ[n_] -> α[n + 1] λ^(m - 1) ψ[n + 1];
```

but it doesn't work. 
Since the recursive method seemed to work, I created a function which multiplies `ψ[m]` by λ `n` times:

```
timesλ[n_] := Nest[Times[λ, #] /. myrule1 &, ψ[m], n] &
```

But this is a very crude way of solving this problem.

Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Could augment with a second form `\[Lambda]^(j_ /; IntegerQ[j] && j >= 1) \[Psi][n_] -> \[Alpha][
    n + j] \[Psi][n + j]`

Comment: Thanks! The rule you suggest is incorrect, but the idea is ok.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed the need for a product. I think the @m_goldberg variation sounds better...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the full form versions of `λ ψ[n]` and  `λ^k ψ[n]`

```
λ ψ[n] // FullForm
```

> Times[λ, ψ[n]]

```
λ^k ψ[n] // FullForm
```

> Times[Power[λ, k],ψ[n]]

you see that the second expression can't match your rule because it contains `Power`. Therefore, as Daniel Lichtblau suggests, you need to have two rules.

```
rules = {λ ψ[n_] -> α[1 + n] ψ[1 + n],
         λ^j_ ψ[n_] -> Product[α[s], {s, n + 1, n + j}] ψ[j + n]};
```

Now you can get both

```
λ ψ[n] /. rules
```

> α[1 + n] ψ[1 + n]

and

```
λ^k ψ[n] /. rules
```

> Product[α[s], {s, n + 1, n + k}] ψ[k + n]

Comment: Looks good, thanks! It is weird that myrule2 didn't bring any output, it 'almost' works on another pc (one λ is left because of different Head on RHS, as you mentioned).

Comment: It appears that Gregory is not following this thread but I think you may learn something from the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 3):

### Preliminary

This can be done with a single rule and an [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) pattern because `Power` has the attribute [`OneIdentity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OneIdentity.html).
As the documentation states:

> The fact that `Times` has attribute `OneIdentity` allows a pattern like `n_. x_` to match `x`.

Observe:

```
{2^y, 3} /. a_Integer^b_. :> {a, b}
```

> ```
> {{2, y}, {3, 1}}
> ```

(`Power` has an internal default of one.)

Note also that I use `RuleDelayed` (short form `:>`) and not `Rule`; this is necessary to correctly localize named patterns on the right hand side of the rule.

### Your operation

With this knowledge we can now adjust your `rule2`; with this formulation we will need `ReplaceRepeated` (short form `//.`):

```
rule = λ^m_. ψ[n_] :> α[n + 1] λ^(m - 1) ψ[n + 1];

λ^3 ψ[n] //. rule
```

> ```
> α[1 + n] α[2 + n] α[3 + n] ψ[3 + n]
> ```

Or if you prefer, the `Product` formulation:

```
rule2 = λ^j_. ψ[n_] :> Product[α[n + s], {s, j}] ψ[j + n];

λ ψ[n] /. rule2

λ^2 ψ[n] /. rule2
```

> ```
> α[1 + n] ψ[1 + n]
>
> α[1 + n] α[2 + n] ψ[2 + n]
> ```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very nice solution.

Comment: @Gregory Welcome back to the site.  I'm glad you found this helpful even now. :-)