# Is there a way to simplify this replacement rule

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

I have a rather big expression which contains many sums of form `q x + w y`. I know that `y` is much smaller than `x` and i want to omit it where possible, namely if both `q` and `w` are integers. So i apply the replacement rule

```
q_?IntegerQ x + w_?IntegerQ y -> q x
```

However this rule obviously doesn't work if either `q` or `w` (or both) is equal to unity because `FullForm` of `q x` contains `Times` and one of `x` doesn't. So to get replacement done i need to use the ugly set of rules

```
{ q_?IntegerQ x + w_?IntegerQ y -> q x , x + w_?IntegerQ y -> x , ... }
```

and in place of dots there are two more rules with `w` and both `w` and `q` omitted.

So the question is whether it is possible (in general) to somehow simplify this ugly set to anything more simple.

Comment: BlankNullSequence or {q___?IntegerQ x + w___?IntegerQ y -> q x}

Comment: Do you want 0s to match? What about `q_. x + w_. y /; IntegerQ /@ And[q, w]`?

Comment: (Better `And @@ IntegerQ /@ {q, w}`, otherwise `q=w=True` would match)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take advantage of the [`OneIdentity`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OneIdentity.html) attribute of `Times` as it affects pattern matching<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30591/121),[(2)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20715/121),[(3)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30919/121)</sup> by making `q` and `w` [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html). (As Rojo shows in a comment above.)  [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Condition.html) is then used to check the `q` and `w` matches.

```
{3 x + 7 y, 2 x + E y, x + 5 y} /.
  q_. x + w_. y /; IntegerQ[q] && IntegerQ[w] :> q x
```

> ```
> {3 x, 2 x + E y, x}
> ```

Note that I used [`RuleDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RuleDelayed.html) rather than `Rule` to localize `q`.