# Dot when used in a pattern becomes Times... Why?

Tags: pattern-matching, syntax

```
 In[1] := Hold[a.b] // FullForm
Out[1] := Hold[Dot[a,b]]
```

So far so good.

```
 In[2] := Hold[a_.b_] // FullForm
Out[2] := Hold[Times[Optional[Pattern[a,Blank[]]],Pattern[b,Blank[]]]]
```

Why does the Dot become Times? I have a feeling it has something to do with the Optional that also appears, but I can't find anything that explains what's going on in the documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the documentation for [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html):

> The special form `s_.` is equivalent to `Optional[s_]` and can be used to represent function arguments which, if omitted, should be replaced by default values globally specified for the functions in which they occur.

This explains the result your are receiving.

Thus, it seems you have a precedence problem, and a possible workaround is:

```
Hold[(a_).(b_)] // FullForm
```

and get

> ```
> Hold[Dot[Pattern[a, Blank[]], Pattern[b, Blank[]]]
> ```

Comment: Even `FullForm[Hold[(a_).b_]]` is enough since now there are no special forms related to `.` in the expression. +1.

Comment: I have never seen an application of `Optional`...

Comment: Don't know how I missed that in the docs! Thanks.

Comment: A single space will also work: `Hold[a_ .b_] // FullForm`.  @Murta `Optional` is quite useful.  A few examples from my own answers: [(17498)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/17498/121),
[(20715)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/20715/121),
[(29366)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29366/121),
[(30591)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30591/121),
[(30919)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30919/121),
[(47844)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47844/121),
[(51670)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51670/121).