# Documentation on the attribute OneIdentity

Tags: documentation, attributes, optional-arguments

The [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OneIdentity.html?q=OneIdentity) on the attribute OneIdentity says

> `OneIdentity` is an attribute that can be assigned to a symbol `f` to indicate that
>   `f[x]`, `f[f[x]]`, etc. are all equivalent to `x` for the purpose of pattern
>   matching.

Then why does the input

```
SetAttributes[f,OneIdentity]
MatchQ[x, f[_]]
```

return `False`? On the other hand (from the examples in the documentation), the following input returns `True`:

```
SetAttributes[f, OneIdentity]
MatchQ[a, f[x_: 0, y_]]
```

Is there a problem with the documentation or am I misunderstanding it?

Comment: What happens if you use `f[__]` (`BlankSequence` instead of `Blank`)?

Comment: See [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71498/20253) for an answer to your question.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. Still returns false.

Comment: I think the definition given [in the answer of the linked question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71738/12908) is slightly wrong. For example, `MatchQ[a,f[x_: 0, y_, __]]` returns `False` even though there is one optional argument in the first two pattern argument positions (as stated in the linked answer).


A more correct definition would be: there has to be at least one optional argument in `f[...]` and besides optional arguments there can be at most one argument that is not optional.