# How to get f[x] to match with f[c_., x] when OneIdentity doesn't match

Tags: pattern-matching, argument-patterns, attributes

After setting:

```
SetAttributes[f, OneIdentity]
Default[f] = 1;
```

We have the following successful matches:

```
MatchQ[f[x, y, z, a], f[n_. , x, y, z, a]]  (* True *)
MatchQ[f[x, y, z], f[n_. , x, y, z]]        (* True *)
MatchQ[f[x, y], f[n_. , x, y]]              (* True *)
```

but

```
MatchQ[f[x], f[n_. , x]]                    (* False *)
```

What do I need to do so that the case with one argument matches?

Note: something spooky is happening:

```
f[x] /. f[n_., y_] :> f[n, y]
(*  f[1, f[x]]  *)
```

instead of  `(*  f[1, x] *)`.

Comment: I do know that `OneIdentity` is a little weird. [See here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/71738/29734).

Comment: But as far as your "something spooky", since all of `f[x]`, `f[f[x]]` are the same as `x` for the purpose of pattern matching, perhaps `x` matches the pattern `f[n_., y_]`, and so it gets replaced by `f[x]`.

Comment: Yes: Try `x /. f[y_, n_.] :> f[y, n]`.

Comment: as a workaround simply do `MatchQ[f[x], f[n_., x] | f[x]]`

Comment: another thing that works:  `MatchQ[f[x], f[n_., f[x]]]`  (works for multi arg cases as well ).

Comment: By the way, every single one of your `MatchQ`'s return `True` when `f` does *not* have the `OneIdentity` `Attribute`, which means the only thing `OneIdentity` is doing is changing `MatchQ[f[x], f[n_. , x]]` from `True` to `False`.